# Customize color based on value (several times)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following type of html code :

```
<div class="note">
<h4>
<span>3</span>
</h4>
</div>

<div class="note">
<h4>
<span>1</span>
</h4>
</div>
```

I am using JS in order to style the span text based on the value :

```
jQuery(function () {
// Score Color
var score = parseInt(jQuery('.note h4 span').text().trim());
var color = 'red';
if (!isNaN(score)) {
    if (score >= 3) {
        color = 'orange';
    }
    if (score >= 4) {
        color = 'green';
    }
    jQuery('.note h4 span').css('color', color);
}
});
```

It works well when I have only one "note" class. However with several "note" class it doesn't work. What is the best way to solve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Your code only works for the first instance of the note class because a variable can only store one thing. You should either iterate over all `jQuery('.note h4 span')` or get an array containing all of them and iterate over that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate all items with that class:

```
jQuery(function () {
    // Score Color
    $('.note h4 span').each(function () {
        var score = parseInt($(this).text().trim());

        var color = 'red';
        if (!isNaN(score)) {
            if (score >= 3) {
                color = 'orange';
            }
            if (score >= 4) {
                color = 'green';
            }
        }
        //Just put this outside the if.
        //And use keyword this
        jQuery(this).css('color', color);
    });    
});
```

[.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) iterates all items on the object.

`$('.note h4 span')` returns a list of items that correspond to that selector.
If anything on my explanation is incorrect just let me know, I'm also a rookie with JQuery.

Comment: Awesome, works really well ! You are less a rookie than I am ;-) 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey no problem, if it helps and it works make sure to mark it as answered :)

Comment: Actually I spoke to quickly... I've tried your code, and every value goes to red....

Comment: Just updated, Should work now. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p2j6eqy4/5/

Answer (score 0):

1) The following line will return "31", I guess it's not what you expect :

```
var score = parseInt(jQuery('.note h4 span').text().trim());
```

2) The following line will affect all DOM elements which are "span" in "h4" with a class "note", I guess it's not what you expect :

```
 jQuery('.note h4 span').css('color', color);
```

You have to iterate over an oject with all spans elements in order to change color for each of them with a jquery "each" loop.

Check the following JsFiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/2ho83qeg/